# Post ajax values to MVC Action Result

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok, so I have the following Ajax get request going to a `[HttpPost]` controller method in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

The javascript function shown here successfully posts the values to the server side:

```
<script>
 function get_row() {
        var one = document.getElementById("data_table").rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
        var two = document.getElementById("data_table").rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
        var result = one + "," + two;
        //var result = {};
        //result.one = document.getElementById("data_table").rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
        //result.two = document.getElementById("data_table").rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
        if (result != null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: "/Manage/CreateGroupRoleRestriction",
                //url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action= "CreateGroupRoleRestriction", controller= "Manage", one = "one", two = "two"})',,
                data: { one, two },
                //params: { one, two }
                /*dataType: String,*/
                //success: alert(result)
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Error");
        }

    }
</script>
```

However, the issue is that the string values will not post to the Action Result, see below.

The values "one" and "two" are null.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Manage/CreateGroupRoleRestriction?{one,two}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]        
public ActionResult CreateGroupRoleRestriction(FormCollection formCollection, string message2, string one, string two)
{   
    UserDataBusinessLayer userDataBusinessLayer = new UserDataBusinessLayer();
    userDataBusinessLayer.Restrict1(message2);

    UserDataBusinessLayer userDataBusinessLayer2 = new UserDataBusinessLayer();
    userDataBusinessLayer2.Restrict2();

    try
    {
        UserData userData = new UserData();
        TryUpdateModel(userData);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                            
            userData.RoleName = formCollection["RoleName"];
            UserDataBusinessLayer userDataBusinessLayer3 = new UserDataBusinessLayer();
            userDataBusinessLayer3.CreateGroupRestriction(userData, message2, one.ToString(), two.ToString());                    
                
            return RedirectToAction("CreateGroupRoleRestriction");
        }
        else
        {
            userData.RoleName = formCollection["RoleName"];
            UserDataBusinessLayer userDataBusinessLayer4 = new UserDataBusinessLayer();
            userDataBusinessLayer4.CreateGroupRestriction(userData, message2, one.ToString(), two.ToString());

            return RedirectToAction("CreateGroupRoleRestriction");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log(ex);
        return RedirectToAction("CreateGroupRoleRestriction");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing 'type' in ajax to 'post'.

```
type: 'post'
```